# databind keno ui grid with external API

Tags: javascript, api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've used kendo ui with server side processing before. Now I have this external API data:

http://spsight.cloudapp.net/api/Parts/

How can I bind the data source with this API ?

Is there any similar example ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of api you have, if it is supporting OData then you can si[mply give the   Odata Url](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-type).

If not you need to specify the [transport methods](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport) , read,create,update.

[Here is an example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/remote-operations.html) from kendo.